# I'm trying to code on (Jupiter Notebook) but I get this error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mediapipe

````
```
!pip install mediapipe opencv-python

import mediapipe as mp
import cv2
import numpy as np
import uuid
import os
```
````

I used Jupiter Notebook to run this code

error:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sljDY.jpg

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block in body of question instead of a screenshot. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Try restarting the kernel and if that doesnt work try closing the notebook and then check for updates in ipython and jupyter-notebook and try again.